# Change number of copies displayed in PrintDialog box

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, crystal-reports

I am working on Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005. I need to change the default printer, and the number of copies to 2 as compared to the default of 1.

I have succeeded to change the default printer using below code.

```
static int SetAsDefaultPrinter(string printerDevice)
{
    int ret = 0;
    try
    {   
        string path = "win32_printer.DeviceId='" + printerDevice + "'";
        using (ManagementObject printer = new ManagementObject(path))
        {
            ManagementBaseObject outParams =
            printer.InvokeMethod("SetDefaultPrinter",
            null, null);
            ret = (int)(uint)outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value;                
        }
    }
}
```

How can I change the number of copies printed?

Comment: just to make sure, WinForms or WebForms?

Comment: You could always roll your own Print settings dialog and use the PrintToPrinter method on your ReportDocument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net Framework doesn't provide any mechanism to override the default print functionality. So I disabled the default print button, and added a button name Print.Code for the Event Handler follows below.

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PrintDialog printDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

        printDialog1.Document = pd;
        printDialog1.ShowNetwork = true;
        printDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;
        printDialog1.AllowSelection = false;
        printDialog1.AllowCurrentPage = false;
        printDialog1.PrinterSettings.Copies = (short)this.CopiesToPrint;
        printDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = this.PrinterToPrint;
        DialogResult result = printDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            PrintReport(pd);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void PrintReport(PrintDocument pd)
{
    ReportDocument rDoc=(ReportDocument)crvReport.ReportSource;
    // This line helps, in case user selects a different printer 
    // other than the default selected.
    rDoc.PrintOptions.PrinterName = pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName; 
    // In place of Frompage and ToPage put 0,0 to print all pages,
    // however in that case user wont be able to choose selection.
    rDoc.PrintToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.Copies, false, pd.PrinterSettings.FromPage,
       pd.PrinterSettings.ToPage); 
}
```

Comment: If you change the default printer here, does it have any ramifications for the system/other applications?