# C# ProcessStartInfo Print Copies To Printer

Tags: c#, printing

I want to be able to print multiple copies set from the printer dialogue and send them to the printer.

```
using (System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog printerDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog())
{
    string printer;
    if (printerDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printer = printerDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(GetDocPath("StickerBlank.docx", Client.ClientID.ToString()));
        for (int i = 0; i < printerDialog.PrinterSettings.Copies; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            using (var regWord = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Winword.exe"))
            {
                //string arguments = String.Format(@"-t ""{0}"" ""{1}""", printerDialo, printer);
                if (regWord == null)
                {
                    info.Arguments = "\"" + printer + "\"";
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    info.UseShellExecute = true;
                    info.Verb = "Print";
                }
                else
                {
                    info.Arguments = "\"" + printer + "\"";
                    info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                    info.UseShellExecute = true;
                    info.Verb = "PrintTo";
                }
            }   
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
        }
    }
}
```

It works but the problem is that the word document which is my template opens  as much as copies are set from the printdialog. Is there a way to specify that i want 5 copies as arguments?

Comment: In your loop you are opening multiple instances.  Why don't use one instance of printdialog and specify the number of copies?

Comment: I am using one instance of printdialog please look at the code. I dont know how to pass the number of copies which I choose from the dialog to the process.

Comment: True you are using one instance of printdialog, but you are opening mutlple instances of your docx file with:   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);

Comment: I know the problem any ideas how to solve this issue with one process instance

Comment: Have you looked here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186970/change-number-of-copies-displayed-in-printdialog-box

Comment: Better, have you tried the PrinterSettings.Copies Property ??

Comment: I am using PrinterSettings.Copies in order to loop from the selected number of copies. I want to be able somehow to specifty that i have 5 copies for example and execute the process only once.